# Parse query to print all results in a given time frame

Tags: date, parse-platform

I would like to create a query that will allow a user to type in a starting date, and print out all records of a table from that date until the current time. I keep getting "Error 102: invalid field type for find". Any suggestions?

```
function billingReport(){       
    startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("startDate").value);
    var caseList = Parse.Object.extend("Cases");
    var query = new Parse.Query(caseList);
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", "startDate");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
            // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                var object = results[i];
                alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: correction, typo in my code. It should read:  alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get("**customer**"));

Comment: not using compatible data types inside query predicate... https://parse.com/questions/current-date-now-in-parse-cloud   compare "createdAt" to another field of type=date

Comment: I think @RobertRowntree is saying that OP is comparing createdAt to a string `"startDate"`, rather than to the local variable `startDate`, which (we hope) is a date object.

Comment: new Date(string.valueOf.startdate)  will create object of proper type to then use in your query predicate

Comment: Thank you for the responses! @RobertRowntree I used that new Date command you posted as the comparing value for createdAt. I know the database has entries within the range of dates I am testing, but the query is reporting back error 107: Empty value provided. I am trying to utilize query.find in another js function and the same thing is happening there. I am wathcing my code in debug menu and I can see that all the attributes have values in them, but for some reason when the query.find part is ran, the query is showing no results. Is the structure of how it is set up wrong?

Comment: try getting a date obj from any class.createdAt col.  Then use that in query instead of making date from string.

Comment: wouldnt my first line in the function create a date object? From looking through the debugger, Ive come to believe that when passing object in that query, it keeps sending null values. If i type in an actual value(in this case a date, in the correct format) it works perfectly fine. So my problem seems to be in the greaterThanOrEqualTo line. Any other suggestions for passing the correct value to the query?

Comment: just to complete this thread, its because the dates were of different types. added .toISOString to startDate and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mentioned in a comment above, but I just wanted to end this topic correctly. The two date objects were of different types, so i added .toISOString to the startDate object and it worked like a charm